# Internet Explorer - saving cookies with path

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, cookies

I am struggling with IE11. I have a website with a lot of tables. Two of them (located in seperate documents) are sorted with the same JavaScript function. I want to save my sorting so that when I move around the website you don't have to click on row names in order to sort again. I am using cookies to achieve this. So I create one cookie BUT with two different paths. So my syntax is like this:

```
document.cookie = 'columnID=th_1;expires=' + expiryDate + ';path=' + window.location.pathname;
```

And this works perfectly fine in Firefox. However IE11 doesn't like this 'path=' parameter. If I use the same syntax without path=

```
document.cookie = 'columnID=th_1;expires=' + expiryDate;
```

it works.

I switched my security options to allow ALL cookies and I added my website adress (localhost) to exceptions.
I googled for setCookies functions and they don't work eighter. I even use console.log to look if syntax of setCookie function is the same as mine and it is!

One more thing

```
document.cookie = 'columnID=th_1;expires=' + expiryDate + ';path=/';
```

This syntax works too in IE but it creates a global cookie for whole website. I want to seperate them.

Comment: You don't have to specify the path. If you don't specify it, it defaults " _to the current path of the current document location_ ". [`Document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/cookie)

Comment: If I don't specify the path it creates a global cookie for the whole website. I want to seperete them.

Comment: use separate crumbs.eg. 
table1=th_1;table2=th_2; 
use a javascript cookie utility (see https://plainjs.com/javascript/utilities/set-cookie-get-cookie-and-delete-cookie-5/) to read/write individual crumbs.